# Find if string exist in a vector of structs

Tags: c, vector, struct, comparison

Good afternoon,

I'm here with a doubt that i am not able to overcome and i've tried a number of ways. I'm doing a program that among other things the user has to enter data about a product where the serial number has to be unique and of type char.  What is happening is that when i type the 1st product serial number the program returns that is already a product with this serial number despite being the 1st.

Here's the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char numeroserie;
    char descricao;
    float preco;
} stProduto;
/********************** Funcoes dos produtos *************************/
void inserirProduto(stProduto produtos[], int *contadorProdutos);
int procurarNumeroserie(stProduto produtos[], int contadorProdutos, char produtoAProcurar);

int main()
{
    stProduto produtos[500];
    int contadorProdutos=0;
    inserirProduto(produtos,&contadorProdutos);
    return 0;
}
void inserirProduto(stProduto produtos[], int *contadorProdutos)
{
    char string1;
    char posicao;
    do
    {
        printf("Introduza o numero de serie do produto:");
        scanf("%s",&string1);
        posicao =  procurarNumeroserie(produtos,*contadorProdutos, string1);
        if (posicao == 0)
        {
            printf("Ja existe um produto com esse numero de serie!!!\n");
        }
    }
    while(posicao == 0);
    strcpy(produtos[*contadorProdutos].numeroserie,string1);
    (*contadorProdutos)++;
}
int procurarNumeroserie(stProduto produtos[], int contadorProdutos, char produtoAProcurar)
{
   int i;
    char posicao;
    posicao = 0;
    for(i = 0 ; i < contadorProdutos ; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(produtos[i].numeroserie, produtoAProcurar) == 0)
        {
            posicao=i;
            i=contadorProdutos;
        }
    }
    return posicao;
}
```

Someone help please !!I am already getting frustrated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong, `char` is not a string type in c, it's an integer type.

A string is defined as a sequence of bytes non-`nul` that are followed by a `nul` byte.

They type `char` is 1 byte and hence a string can be an array of `char`, like the following

```
char string[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
/*                                           ^ nul: it's mandatory 
 *                                             for this to be a 
 *                                             string 
 */
```

The code you posted above seems to be Java originally with some fixes to make it compile, but if you enable compilation warnigs the compiler will really piss you off.

You can build a string from an array like I did above, or by using a pointer of `char`, in that case you need to point to an array or to dynamic memory allocated using `malloc()`.

An example would be

```
char *hello;
hello = malloc(6);
if (hello == NULL)
    return ERROR; /* or whatever is need but do not continue */
strcpy(hello, "Hello");
/* do whatever you want with hello */
free(hello);
```

Comment: It requires work, I can do it if you pay me 20$ paypal.

Comment: @BRBL I am sorry, I don't have it either that's why I want it. Is this homework?

Comment: @BRBL Since it's homework you need to **learn** so please read about strings in c.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to put i to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char numeroserie[9];
    char descricao;
    float preco;
} stProduto;
/********************** Funcoes dos produtos *************************/
void inserirProduto(stProduto produtos[], int *contadorProdutos);
int procurarNumeroserie(stProduto produtos[], int contadorProdutos, char produtoAProcurar[9]);

int main()
{
    stProduto produtos[500];
    int contadorProdutos=0;
    inserirProduto(produtos,&contadorProdutos);
    return 0;
}
void inserirProduto(stProduto produtos[], int *contadorProdutos)
{
    char string1[9];
    char posicao;
    do
    {
        printf("Introduza o numero de serie do produto:");
        scanf("%s",&string1);
        posicao =  procurarNumeroserie(produtos,*contadorProdutos, string1);
        if (posicao == 0)
        {
            printf("Ja existe um produto com esse numero de serie!!!\n");
        }
    }
    while(posicao == 0);
    strcpy(produtos[*contadorProdutos].numeroserie,string1);
    (*contadorProdutos)++;
}
int procurarNumeroserie(stProduto produtos[], int contadorProdutos, char produtoAProcurar[9])
{
   int i;
    char posicao;
    posicao = 0;
    for(i = 0 ; i < contadorProdutos ; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(produtos[i].numeroserie, produtoAProcurar) == 0)
        {
            posicao=i;
            i=contadorProdutos;
        }
    }
    return posicao;
}
```

Putting numeroserie [8]  i assure that the user just insert 8 characters ??

Thanks